# Different results when using Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm learning how to use Selenium with Python by trying to scrap Matrix ITA software (in case you don't know that, it helps to find good flight fares). I'm filling the whole form with Selenium exactly in the same way as manually (same airports, same dates, multicity: AAA-BBB,BBB-AAA,CCC-DDD).

When running the script I get completely different results. Manually the flight CCC-DDD is operated by airline X, when running Selenium - it is operated by airline Y. It dramatically changes the overall price of whole booking.

Why? I set up the same user agent as well as incognito mode. Is there any trick?

Comment: web browsers get from servers cookies and send them back to server - Selenium may run browser as anonymous user and then server may treat it in different way.

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: @Dan-Dev yes, take a look: https://pastebin.com/t6pajB9g
When I run this script, the cheapest result is 1182EUR. When I search exactly the same route manually, it is 579EUR. It's because of the airline of third flight.